# ext4 filesystem corruption -- maybe hardware error?

Tags: linux, hardware, ssd, ext4, drive-failure

I'm getting these errors in `dmesg` after about half an hour after I turn on the computer:

```
 [ 1355.677957] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): htree_dirblock_to_tree: inode #1318420: (comm updatedb.mlocat) bad entry in directory: directory entry across blocks - block=5251700offset=0(0), inode=1802725748, rec_len=179136, name_len=32
 [ 1355.677973] Aborting journal on device sda2-8.
 [ 1355.678101] EXT4-fs (sda2): Remounting filesystem read-only
 [ 1355.690144] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): htree_dirblock_to_tree: inode #1318416: (comm updatedb.mlocat) bad entry in directory: directory entry across blocks - block=5251699offset=0(0), inode=2194783952, rec_len=53280, name_len=152
 [ 1356.864720] EXT4-fs error (device sda2): htree_dirblock_to_tree: inode #1312795: (comm updatedb.mlocat) bad entry in directory: directory entry across blocks - block=5251176offset=1460(13748), inode=1432317541, rec_len=208208, name_len=119
```

`/dev/sda` is an SSD, and it's using the noop scheduler.

`/etc/fstab` entry:

```
UUID=acb4eefa-48ff-4ee1-bb5f-2dccce7d011f / ext4 errors=remount-ro,noatime,discard,user_xattr 0 1
```

System information:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep /dev/sd
/dev/sda1 /boot ext2 rw,noatime,errors=continue 0 0
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS"
$ uname -a
Linux leetpad 2.6.35-30-generic-pae #61~lucid1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 13 21:14:29 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `smartctl -a`:

```
smartctl version 5.38 [i686-pc-linux-gnu] Copyright (C) 2002-8 Bruce Allen
Home page is http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     STT_FTM28GX25H
Serial Number:    P637510-MIBY-706A009
Firmware Version: 1916
User Capacity:    128,035,676,160 bytes
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Thu Nov 24 20:53:48 2011 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:         (   0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x1d) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x00) Error logging NOT supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0000   005   000   000    Old_age   Offline  In_the_past 0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0000   141   002   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0000   115   002   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
184 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   084   000   000    Old_age   Offline  In_the_past 0
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline  FAILING_NOW 0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline  FAILING_NOW 0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline  FAILING_NOW 0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0000   002   107   000    Old_age   Offline      -       21198
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0000   063   003   000    Old_age   Offline      -       26957
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0000   099   124   000    Old_age   Offline      -       446
201 Soft_Read_Error_Rate    0x0000   024   154   000    Old_age   Offline      -       328
202 TA_Increase_Count       0x0000   115   254   000    Old_age   Offline      -       115
203 Run_Out_Cancel          0x0000   247   245   000    Old_age   Offline      -       83
204 Shock_Count_Write_Opern 0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline  FAILING_NOW 0
205 Shock_Rate_Write_Opern  0x0000   016   039   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
206 Flying_Height           0x0000   005   000   000    Old_age   Offline  In_the_past 0
207 Spin_High_Current       0x0000   055   015   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
208 Spin_Buzz               0x0000   248   001   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
209 Offline_Seek_Performnce 0x0000   095   000   000    Old_age   Offline  In_the_past 0
211 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline  FAILING_NOW 0
212 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline  FAILING_NOW 0
213 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline  FAILING_NOW 0

Warning: device does not support Error Logging
Warning! SMART ATA Error Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

Warning! SMART Self-Test Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


Device does not support Selective Self Tests/Logging
```

I've run memtest for 7 hours, it didn't found any memory errors.

Any obvious ideas what can go wrong in this case? The most reasonable thing I can imagine is that the SSD is silently dropping some write requests, which eventually leads to an EXT4 filesystem inconsistency (but no disk I/O errors). How can this happen? Is there a relevant configuration option I should ensure to be set correctly?

What tools should I use to diagnose the hardware failures? Would it be possible to diagnose the SSD failure without overwriting data?

Comment: `smartctl -a /dev/sda` output?

Comment: @HubertKario: Done.

Answer (score 6):

```
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0000   002   107   000    Old_age   Offline      -       21198
```

It has failed, RMA it.

You may want to run SMART test on it, but with such values it's just a formality, it's highly unlikely it won't fail.

To run a test, use

```
smartctl -t long /dev/sda
```

It will tell you when the test will end, then you run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` again it will show the test result in self test section.

Answer (score 5):

First, you might want to do a full fsck of the root disk.  Sometimes, I have found that the quick check sometimes misses some important errors.  You can do this by either touch a file in the root directory (maybe Linux distribution dependent) but might try

```
 touch /forcefsck
```

AND rebooting OR starting up the rescue CD and doing the performing the fsck of the root there.  By full, I mean use the -f fsck parameter.

Second, is your syslog indicating any hardware errors?

As Mr. Kario indicated, you might look at checking the disk health using smartctl.  I find that some disks that I have used do not report information however.

Comment: `fsck -f`, when booted from the Ubuntu live installer pen drive, has found tons of errors, and fixed them. A subsequent run of fsck didn't find errors. Then, when the normal system was booted, it started emitting ext4 errors again after half an hour. No, the syslog isn't indicating any hardware errors. You can see the full dmesg output (except for the few seconds after boot) in the original question.